# C++ MSVC/GCC/Clang compilers bug

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I discovered what appears to be a mind breaking bug in the 3 compilers from the title. The following code compiles with the latest versions of all three compilers using both the c++11 and c++14 standards, even though it really shouldn't as the "visit_detail" function is not visible to "main".

Correction: I was stupid, not actually a bug in GCC/Clang, seems to be a bug in my MSVC version tho.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>



namespace bug
{
    using namespace std;
    using size_t = unsigned long long;



    namespace detail
    {
        struct visit_stop_t {};
        constexpr bug::detail::visit_stop_t visit_stop = bug::detail::visit_stop_t();



        template <typename Visitor, typename First, typename... Tail>
        void visit_detail(Visitor&& vis, First&& first, Tail&&... tail)
        {
            // code, not necessairy to recreate bug
        }
    }


    template <typename Visitor, typename... Variants>
    void visit(Visitor&& vis, Variants&&... vars)
    {
        bug::detail::visit_detail(bug::forward<Visitor>(vis), bug::forward<Variants>(vars)..., bug::detail::visit_stop);
    }

    template <typename Visitor>
    void visit(Visitor&& vis) = delete;
}

using namespace bug;



// dummy variant, used to test the code
// code is never actually used in this version
template <typename... T>
struct variant
{
    static constexpr bug::size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(T); }


    constexpr variant(int) noexcept {}

    template <bug::size_t I>
    constexpr int get() const noexcept { return 5; }
};

// simple example visitor
// code is never actually used in this version
struct visitor
{
    int operator()(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; return x; }
    double operator()(double x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; return x; }
};



int main()
{
    visitor vis;
    variant<int, double> var = 5;

    // where the trouble is:
    visit_detail(vis, var, bug::detail::visit_stop);  // ADL: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl
    visit_detail(vis, var);  // fails with GCC/Clang, no error with MSVC => MSVC bug maybe


    std::cout << "Press enter to continue . . . ";
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are seeing ADL in action

Comment: `using size_t = unsigned long long;` Why? Why? At least do something like `using size_t = decltype(sizeof(int));`, or better yet, include `<cstddef>`.

Comment: it's just some quick & dirty code sample i put together to show what the bug actually is

Comment: As Andrey says, this is [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), not a bug.

Comment: pretty sure using `bug::detail::visit_stop` brings `bud::detail::visit_detail` into scope as the argument is also inside the same namespace.

Comment: if i remove the bug::detail::visit_stop argument from the function call in main it still compiles

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://rextester.com/HHYSR4399)

Comment: @n.m. it doesn't compile with vc++ 19.10.25019 for x86

Comment: Please improve your question title. At the moment it's completely useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're experiencing is a C++ feature called [**argument-dependent lookup**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), or ADL for short. Basically, if you invoke a function `f` without explicitly qualifying it, the compiler will look for `f` in the namespaces of the arguments that you've passed.

This is what allows `operator<<` for IO streams to work without requiring qualifications:

```
std::cout << 100; // finds std::operator<<(std::ostream&, int);
```

---

In your particular case, the argument `bug::detail::visit_stop` is making the compiler look for `visit_detail` inside the `bug::detail` namespace.

Comment: just updated the post, "visit_detail(vis, arg)" in "main" also works with msvc

Comment: @Zeldhoron Just tested it on gcc.godbolt.com and both GCC and Clang reject the second line.

Comment: yeah, also tested it with them, same, so MSVC bug

Comment: @Zeldhoron Wjhat MSVS are you using?  It fails to compile for me.

Comment: idk, i'm using the one packed with the latest visual studio 2017 version, currently trying to find an actual version number for the vc++ compiler

Comment: @NathanOliver think i found it, the visual studio 2017 developer command prompt gives me "v15.0.26430.6" as a version string

Comment: Enter `cl` in the developer command prompt to get the compiler version.

Comment: You can past the example into http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ to see the failure on the latest version of the compiler.  I think the project settings can override the compiler that is used, so you may be using an older version of the compiler than what the developer command prompt has in the path.